# How do I clear a Firebase Dynamic Link event once I've processed it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase Dynamic Links to receive a deep link in my app and the problem I'm experiencing is the link never goes away. This makes my app respond to the deep link EVERY time it's opened from the icon but oddly enough not from the "alt-tab" menu.

I can clear the dynamic link if I "force quit" the app or rebuild and rerun the app from Android Studio. Not sure why this would clear the event when backgrounding does not, but it's probably a big clue and I just don't understand it.

How do I tell Firebase I've processed a link and it should CLEAR that link so it doesn't launch my app every time with that link?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the answer was pretty simple though hard to find so I'll post it here for future reference. The activity that receives the dynamic link MUST call 'Finish()' after launching the intent to send a message, otherwise the dynamic link will exist forever or until a Force Stop is performed on the app.

Comment: Hi, just post the code snippet here. It will help. Thanks!